# Authorization failure in Springboot returns empty body with 403 status message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I have implemented a custom exception handler that handles all the exception that I am throwing:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppExceptionHandler {
    

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {UserServiceException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object>handleUserServiceException(
                            UserServiceException ex, WebRequest request){
        
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(new Date(), ex.getMessage());
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
    }
    
    //A universal exception handling method
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object>handleUserOtherExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
        
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(new Date(), ex.getMessage());
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
    }

}
```

The Universal exception handler method doesn't gets called for 403 status response, the response body is empty but I want to see a response body.

Below is my Security class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    private final UserService userService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
//  @Autowired
//  AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
    
    public WebSecurity(UserService userService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL)
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
        .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }   
    
    public AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception{
        final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/users/login");
        return filter;
    }
```

Below is my AuthenticationFilter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{
    
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        
        try {
            UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), UserLoginRequestModel.class);
            
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getEmail(), creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
            
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req
            , HttpServletResponse res
            , FilterChain chain
            , Authentication auth)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        String userName = ((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userName)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret())
                .compact();
        
        UserService userService = (UserService) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("userServiceImpl");
        UserDto userDto = userService.getUser(userName);
        
        res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
        res.addHeader(SecurityConstants.USER_ID, userDto.getUserId());
    }
}
```

Below is my AuthorizationFilter:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        
        if(header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        
        if(token != null) {
            token = token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
            
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.getTokenSecret())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            
            if(user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }       
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is my postman response (As you can see the body is empty[image]

I want Spring to handle all other exceptions by calling the overriding `@ExceptionHandler` I have written in the above `AppExceptionHandler` class.

As you can see the response body is empty. How do I return the default or custom object for response body?

Comment: Why do you have all this custom code when all this functionality is already built into spring security?

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure if this is what you are looking for, but If you want to somehow customize the messages from failed authentication have a look on `AuthenticationEntryPoint` like in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication. There you can react on the thrown exception and customize what message and codes to return.